# Get the counts and unique counts of every columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe as follows,

data

```
id  A   B   C   D   E
1   NaN 1   NaN 1   1
1   NaN 2   NaN 2   2
1   NaN 3   NaN NaN 3
1   NaN 4   NaN NaN 4
1   NaN 5   NaN NaN 5
2   NaN 6   NaN NaN 6
2   NaN 7   5   NaN 7
2   NaN 8   6   2   8
2   NaN 9   NaN NaN 9
2   NaN 10  NaN 4   10
3   NaN 11  NaN NaN 11
3   NaN 12  NaN NaN 12
3   NaN 13  NaN NaN 13
3   NaN 14  NaN NaN 14
3   NaN 15  NaN NaN 15
3   NaN 16  NaN NaN 16
```

I am using the following command,

```
pd.DataFrame(data.count().sort_values(ascending=False)).reset_index()
```

and get the following output,

```
    index   0
0   E       16
1   B       16
2   id      16
3   D        4
4   C        2
5   A        0
```

I want the following output,

```
columns count   unique(id) count
E         16           3
B         16           3
D          4           2
C          2           1
A          0           0
```

where count is same as the previous one but the unique(id) count is the unique ids for each columns present. I want both to be as two fields.

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Also, I don't think you need to use the `DataFrame` constructor... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought this question for relevant for both the pythons. So only tagged it on both. I can remove one if it is a mistake

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just wanted to export it to a file to analyse how many values do each variable contain. If there is a better way, can you please tell me to do for both?

Comment: In the future, use the generic `python` tag if the question is applicable to either version. Only use a specific python tag if there is something particular about that version that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Also, I may be missing something obvious, again, but I don't understand what you want by `"unique(id) count`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I want to find the number of unique IDs which has the values for this respective columns. For example B column has values for all the IDs so, the value is 3. but C columns has values only for '2' ID . so the value is 1.

Comment: Ah, I just saw your edit where you removed id 4. That makes sense now.

Comment: Is your DataFrame indexed to `'id'`?

Comment: single ID could have 3-4 entries. So it is not indexed

Comment: ... I'm not sure I understand why it couldn't be an index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
    id   A   B    C    D   E
0    1 NaN   1  NaN  1.0   1
1    1 NaN   2  NaN  2.0   2
2    1 NaN   3  NaN  NaN   3
3    1 NaN   4  NaN  NaN   4
4    1 NaN   5  NaN  NaN   5
5    2 NaN   6  NaN  NaN   6
6    2 NaN   7  5.0  NaN   7
7    2 NaN   8  6.0  2.0   8
8    2 NaN   9  NaN  NaN   9
9    2 NaN  10  NaN  4.0  10
10   3 NaN  11  NaN  NaN  11
11   3 NaN  12  NaN  NaN  12
12   3 NaN  13  NaN  NaN  13
13   3 NaN  14  NaN  NaN  14
14   3 NaN  15  NaN  NaN  15
15   3 NaN  16  NaN  NaN  16
```

Here is a rather inelegant way:

```
In [8]: (df.groupby('id').count() > 0).sum()
Out[8]: 
A    0
B    3
C    1
D    2
E    3
dtype: int64
```

So, simply make your base `DataFrame` as you've specified:

```
In [9]: counts = (df[['A','B','C','D','E']].count().sort_values(ascending=False)).to_frame(name='counts')

In [10]: counts
Out[10]: 
   counts
E      16
B      16
D       4
C       2
A       0
```

And then simply:

```
In [11]: counts['unique(id) counts'] = (df.groupby('id').count() > 0).sum()

In [12]: counts
Out[12]: 
   counts  unique(id) counts
E      16                  3
B      16                  3
D       4                  2
C       2                  1
A       0                  0
```